# Multithreading a shortest path algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, shortest-path

I would like to modify my shortest path finding code to use multithreading and improve its performance. The algorithm must be able to work with negative weights, and as a result, we cannot use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Instead, our approach combines three algorithms: [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), [SPFA_Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_faster_algorithm) (shortest path fast algorithm, an improvement over Bellman-Ford that uses a queue and is faster in some cases), and SPFA_MinHeap (a second variation of SPFA that uses a [minheap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)).

After carrying out a large number of tests, we have determined the optimal conditions for selecting one of the three algorithms based on the size and density of the graph.

The question now is how to integrate multithreading in the most efficient way possible based on the way each algorithm works. If necessary, we are open to rewriting parts of the algorithms to enable multithreading and improve performance. We would like to retain the use of these three algorithms since they have proven to be very efficient so far, and we hope to preserve the performance gains obtained from previous work while achieving maximum optimization through multithreading.

We're quite satisfied with the single-threaded code itself, and all the headers and used methods are properly defined and tested in separate files (which can be provided upon request).
The request concerns the search for the most efficient strategy to implement multithreading into the current logic.

Here is the code in question:

```
/**
 * Computes the shortest path between a given source node and all other nodes in a weighted graph using either the Bellman-Ford or SPFA_SLF algorithm based on the density and number of nodes in the graph.
 *
 * Arguments:
 *     links: A 2D array of integers representing the links between nodes. Each row represents a link and contains the indices of the two nodes and the cost of the link.
 *     links_size: The number of links in the links array.
 *     s: The index of the starting node.
 *     dist: An array of size nb_nodes to store the shortest distances from each node to s.
 *     path: An array of size nb_nodes to store the shortest paths from each node to s.
 *     nb_nodes: The total number of nodes in the graph.
 *
 * Returns:
 *     0 if the computation succeeded, 1 if a negative cycle was detected in the graph.
 **/

int shortest_path(sint links[][3], uint links_size, uint s, lsint *dist, uint *path, uint nb_nodes)
{
    // Select algorithm based on graph density and number of nodes
    if (links_size <= 100 || nb_nodes <= 100)
    {
        return bellman_ford(links, links_size, s, dist, path, nb_nodes);
    }
    else if (((double)links_size / (double)(nb_nodes)) < 1)
    {
        return SPFA_queue(links, links_size, s, dist, path, nb_nodes);
    }
    else
    {
        return SPFA_minheap(links, links_size, s, dist, path, nb_nodes);
    }
}

// Version 1: classical Bellman-Ford algorithm
int bellman_ford(sint links[][3], uint links_size, uint s, lsint *dist, uint *path, uint nb_nodes)
{
    int updates;
    uint i;
    uint j;
    uint k;

    // Initialize all elements of dist to INT64_MAX ("infinity").
    for (i = 0; i < nb_nodes; i++)
    {
        dist[i] = INT64_MAX;
    }

    // Initialise path
    memset(path, -1, nb_nodes * sizeof(sint));

    dist[s] = 0;

    // Perform nb_nodes - 1 iterations of Bellman-Ford algorithm
    for (i = 0; i < nb_nodes - 1; i++)
    {
        updates = 0;
        // For each link in the links array, attempt to update shortest distances for each node.
        for (j = 0; j < links_size; j++)
        {
            uint node_from = links[j][0];
            uint node_to = links[j][1];
            lsint cost = links[j][2];

            // If a shorter distance is found, store it in the dist array and update the path array
            if ((dist[node_from] != INT64_MAX) && (dist[node_from] + cost < dist[node_to]))
            {
                dist[node_to] = dist[node_from] + cost;
                path[node_to] = node_from;
                updates++;
            }
        }

        // If no update was made during the previous iteration, exit the loop
        if (updates == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check for negative cycle in the graph
    for (k = 0; k < links_size; k++)
    {
        uint node_from = links[k][0];
        uint node_to = links[k][1];
        lsint cost = links[k][2];

        // If a shorter distance is still found, there is a negative cycle
        if ((dist[node_from] != INT64_MAX) && (dist[node_from] + cost < dist[node_to]))
        {
            // printf("Negative cycle detected\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


// Version 2: SPFA using small label first method and a queue
int SPFA_queue(sint links[][3], uint links_size, uint s, lsint *dist, uint *path, uint nb_nodes)
{
    queue_t *queue = create_queue(); // Initialize the queue
    if (queue == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for queue.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    uint i;

    uint *length = calloc(nb_nodes, sizeof *length); // Array to store the number of nodes in the shortest path for each node in the graph.
    if (length == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for length.\n");
        free_queue(queue);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize all elements of dist to INT64_MAX ("infinity").
    for (i = 0; i < nb_nodes; i++)
    {
        dist[i] = INT64_MAX;
    }

    // Initialise path
    memset(path, -1, nb_nodes * sizeof(sint));

    dist[s] = 0;       // Set the distance of the source node to 0
    enqueue(queue, s); // Add the source node to the queue
    length[s] = 1;

    bool *in_queue = calloc(nb_nodes, sizeof(bool));
    in_queue[s] = true;

    // While the queue is not empty, perform iterations of the algorithm
    while (!is_empty(queue))
    {
        uint current_node = dequeue(queue); // Dequeue the next node to process
        in_queue[current_node] = false;
        // If the length of the shortest path for any link reaches nb_nodes, there is a negative cycle in the graph
        if (length[current_node] >= nb_nodes)
        {
            // printf("Negative cycle detected\n");
            free(length);
            free(in_queue);
            free_queue(queue);
            return 1;
        }

        int min_node = -1;
        lsint min_dist = INT64_MAX;

        // Iterate through all the links in the graph
        for (i = 0; i < links_size; i++)
        {
            // If the current link starts from the dequeued node (current_node)
            if (links[i][0] == current_node)
            {
                uint node_from = links[i][0];
                uint node_to = links[i][1];
                lsint cost = links[i][2];

                // If a shorter path is found, update the distances and paths
                if (dist[node_from] + cost < dist[node_to])
                {
                    dist[node_to] = dist[node_from] + cost;
                    path[node_to] = node_from;
                    length[node_to] = length[node_from] + 1;

                    // If the destination node (node_to) is not in the queue, enqueue it
                    if (!in_queue[node_to])
                    {
                        enqueue(queue, node_to);
                        in_queue[node_to] = true;
                    }
                }

                // Update the minimum distance and node for Small Label First (SLF)
                if (dist[node_to] < min_dist)
                {
                    min_dist = dist[node_to];
                    min_node = node_to;
                }
            }
        }
        if (min_node != -1)
        {
            // Move the node with the minimum distance to the front of the queue
            move_to_front(queue, min_node);
        }
    }

    free(length);
    free(in_queue);
    free_queue(queue);
    return 0;
}


// Version 3: SPFA using a min_heap
int SPFA_minheap(sint links[][3], uint links_size, uint s, lsint *dist, uint *path, uint nb_nodes)
{
    // Create a min heap to store the nodes and their distances.
    MinHeap *heap = create_minheap(nb_nodes);
    if (heap == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for min heap.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint i;

    // Allocate memory for an integer array to keep track of whether a node is already in the heap.
    uint *in_heap = calloc(nb_nodes, sizeof *in_heap);
    if (in_heap == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for in_heap.\n");
        free_minheap(heap);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create an array to store the number of nodes in the shortest path for each node in the graph.
    uint *length = calloc(nb_nodes, sizeof *length); // Array to store the number of nodes in the shortest path for each node in the graph.
    if (length == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for length.\n");
        free_minheap(heap);
        free(in_heap);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Initialize all elements of dist to INT64_MAX ("infinity").
    for (i = 0; i < nb_nodes; i++)
    {
        dist[i] = INT64_MAX;
    }

    // Initialize all elements of `path` to -1.
    memset(path, -1, nb_nodes * sizeof(sint));

    // Create an adjacency list to represent the graph.
    adjacency_node_t **adj_list = create_adjacency_list(nb_nodes, links, links_size);
    if (adj_list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for adj_list.\n");
        free(length);
        free(in_heap);
        free_minheap(heap);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Set the distance of the source node to 0.
    dist[s] = 0;

    // Add the source node to the heap.
    heap = insert_minheap(heap, s);
    in_heap[s] = 1;

    // Set the length of the shortest path for the source node to 1.
    length[s] = 1;

    // While the heap is not empty, perform iterations of the algorithm
    while (heap->size != 0)
    {
        // Extract the node with the minimum distance from the heap.
        uint current_node = get_min(heap);
        heap = delete_minimum(heap);
        in_heap[current_node] = 0;

        // If the length of the shortest path for any link reaches nb_nodes, there is a negative cycle in the graph
        if (length[current_node] >= nb_nodes)
        {
            // printf("Negative cycle detected\n");
            free(length);
            free_adjacency_list(adj_list, nb_nodes);
            free(in_heap);
            free_minheap(heap);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        adjacency_node_t *adj_node = adj_list[current_node];

        // Loop over all the edges that start from the current node
        while (adj_node != NULL)
        {
            uint node_to = adj_node->node_to;
            lsint cost = adj_node->cost;

            // If a shorter path is found, update the distances and paths
            if (dist[current_node] + cost < dist[node_to])
            {
                dist[node_to] = dist[current_node] + cost;
                path[node_to] = current_node;
                length[node_to] = length[current_node] + 1;

                // If the destination node (node_to) is not in the heap, insert it
                if (!in_heap[node_to])
                {
                    insert_minheap(heap, node_to);
                    in_heap[node_to] = 1;
                }
            }
            adj_node = adj_node->next;
        }
    }

    free(length);
    free_adjacency_list(adj_list, nb_nodes);
    free_minheap(heap);
    free(in_heap);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Not all algorithms can be (efficiently) parallelized. Path-finding algorithms are generally poor candidates for parallelization. Here, unless you have graphs with a very large average amount of edges on each node, I do not see any efficient way to benefit from having multiple threads. Indeed, iterative processes cannot be parallelized over time and multithreading is only useful for heavy-grained computations (ie. lasting at least 10 µs, that is, generally >30_000 of cycles). This does not mean the code cannot be optimized -- Just not using multiple threads.

Comment: ```unless you have graphs with a very large average amount of edges on each node``` That's exactly the case, it is used for graphs over tens or hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of nodes and edges. Computations are way over 10 µs and 30_000 of cycles (some we have tested lasted seconds). I guess multithreading does make sense here. How would you make it then ?

Comment: Ok, this is quite unusual. Regarding the "10 µs", I was refering to the time of the parallel section which is typically the time to check all the edges of a node. This time should be small, even on large graphs with millions of nodes. Thus, I do not expect graphs with ~10K edges/node to benefit from using multiple threads. However, it might worth it for ~100K edges/node and ~1M edges/node should be a relatively good use-case for using multiple threads assuming the code. This is especially true if you run this on a computing machine with many cores : the multithreading overhead is often high.

Comment: So, what's your advice for multihreading the code in this case?

Comment: The simplest solution is certainly to use OpenMP to do that. However, this is not so simple here due to the non-trivial reduction. One issue is that the target node can be certainly shared by multiple edges. You can add a per-node lock but I wonder if this will be efficient. In fact, I missed the fact that the condition appear to be be dependent of the update and past updates that could be done by other threads. If values of `links` are unpredictable, then the only way to parallelize this is to a partitioning which is probably more expensive than the actual computation...

Comment: https://github.com/qiansunn/BellmanFord/blob/master/openmp_bellman_ford.cpp should help you.